# Angular refresh scope from service with initial data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service returning static JSON data saving to a `$scope` variable like this:

```
$scope.workout = Workouts.get(id);
```

I´m manipulation this `$scope.workout` with `shift()` and `slice()`. When I try to set `$scope.workout` to the initial data from the Service, this does not work.

```
$scope.workout = Workouts.get(id);
```

The `$scope.workout` has been changed. I thought that another call of the service would refresh the data? Am I wrong? How to get the initial data saved in the service?

Comment: Are you returning JSON or already converted JSON ?

Comment: I´m returning an Object. Sorry for that mistake.

Comment: Please post complete code.

Comment: What is inside the `Workouts.get()`? Is that using any non-angular asynchronous code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `object` is a **reference type**. So why you return it from the `service`, it returns it's `reference`. It means that you have `2 reference` to the same object (from the service and in the scope). So if you change the object from one reference, it will be changed for another reference too.
You need to copy your object.
Simply you can do it by

```
angular.copy(Workouts.get(id), $scope.workout);
```

And work with your `$scope.workout` in your controller.

Comment: I want to get exactly that object what I have hardcoded to my service. How to do that?

Comment: @m1crdy see the edited.Can you please show your object ?

Comment: Got it:   $scope.workout = angular.copy(Workouts.get($scope.workoutId), $scope.workout);

Comment: @m1crdy no need to assign to `$scope.workout` again.

Answer (score 1):

1 workaround can be, copy your `$scope.workout` to another **Object** and assign it back to `$scope.workout`.

```
$scope.workout = Workouts.get(id);

var copyObj = angular.copy($scope.workout);
```

Comment: Will it work? How could you make sure that the angular.copy is called after http get is resolved? I suspect that the `copyObj` will have an empty JSON all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this for an edit feature, make a copy of the object to make edits to so it doesn't affect the original.

```
$scope.workoutTarget = Workouts.get(id);
$scope.workout = angular.copy($scope.workout);

//you're free to make edits to $scope.workout without affecting the service
```

In your save function, commit the changes by merging the objects.

```
angular.merge($scope.workoutTarget, $scope.workout)
```

Now `$scope.workoutTarget` will have the edits applied to it.

Comment: I was typing a similar answer. Will it work? How could you make sure that the angular.copy is called after http get is resolved? I suspect that the `$scope.workout` will have an empty JSON all the time.

Comment: The OP said the get method is returning an object, not a promise.

Comment: I assumed that he was using `$resource`.

Comment: I thought it was asynchronous at first too, but his comment on the question says it's returning an object.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure where your code is wrong (I am not that great at AngularJS!) A quick hack you can use is this:
Assign the initial data to to a new scope variable THEN assign your workout variable from our new scope variable. Now we can refresh workout from our new variable at any time.

Answer (score -1):

You could try $route.reload to refresh the injected data.